# How to find non-British non-ASCII non-LaTeX characters for pdftex?

Tags: grep, character-encoding, ascii

I am debugging my tex file by eliminating all technical flaws in the systems. I cannot find anything wrong in my document with Tex community [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/340811/13173) and myself so I think there can be something non-ASCII characters complicating `pdflatex`. Sample of LaTeX warnings which me and my friends do not understand, since we do not understand the origin

```
Underfull \hbox (badness 1019) in paragraph at lines 4--10
\T1/lmr/m/n/12 (+20) Avail-able from [][]$\T1/lmtt/m/n/12 http : / / www . dyna
med . com / login . aspx ? direct = true & site =
[50] [51] [52] [53]
Underfull \hbox (badness 1019) in paragraph at lines 332--338
\T1/lmr/m/n/12 (+20) Avail-able from [][]$\T1/lmtt/m/n/12 http : / / www . dyna
med . com / login . aspx ? direct = true & site =
) (./deliminated.figures.tex [54]
```

Things which I have done to try to eliminate all non-British non-ASCII characters in .tex and .bib files

1. Eliminate non-ASCII characters in .tex and .bib

   ```
   # http://stackoverflow.com/a/9395552/54964
   grep --color='auto' -P -n "[\x80-\xFF]" file.tex
   grep --color='auto' -P -n "[\x80-\xFF]" work.bib
   ```
2. ...

I am interested in if the grep is sufficient for searching all non-ASCII characters.

### Tools tested but no benefit after Gilles' [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/326286/16920)

1. `grep --color='auto' -P -n '[^\x00-\x7F]' file.tex`
2. `grep -P "[\x80-\xFF]" file.tex`
3. `perl -ane '{ if(m/[[:^ascii:]]/) { print  } }' file.tex`
4. `grep --color='auto' -P -n "[^[:ascii:]]" file.txt`

### Things I am not sure

1. Gilles' answer here `LC_ALL=C grep '[^ -~]' file.tex` but it finds LaTeX syntax characters as non-ASCII. Is this right?

TeXLive: 2016
OS: Debian 8.5
Locale: British

Comment: you may want to prefix that with `LC_ALL=C`, so `LC_ALL=C grep --color='auto' -P -n "[\x80-\xFF]" file.tex`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`[\x80-\xFF]` only includes code points from 128 to 255. Depending on the locale, specifically on the character encoding, this may or may not be the set of non-ASCII characters. It is only the case in 8-bit encodings. (ASCII-based 8-bit encodings, to be precise, but you're extremely unlikely to encounter anything else.) In locales where a character isn't a single byte, including UTF-8 which is the de facto standard, `[\x80-\xFF]` is only a small subset of non-ASCII characters.

The easiest way to search for non-ASCII characters is to impose the C locale. In the C locale, a character is a byte. Using a unibyte locale also makes some versions of GNU grep considerably faster.

```
LC_ALL=C grep --color='auto' -P -n "[\x80-\xFF]" file.tex
```

Comment: I was going to suggest `recode`, and then I noticed that `echo œ | recode utf8..tex` produces `oe`. Yeech.